# When performing a linearizing transformation, do I apply transformation to dummy variables?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, data-transformation, linearity

Suppose I wanted to transform variables to achieve linearity ([e.g.](http://stattrek.com/regression/linear-transformation.aspx?Tutorial=AP)),
would I omit the dummy variables from the transformation?

```
VOL TRGT NPI    Q1  Q2  Q3  COMP NPI
7428    1.49    1   0   0   8.31
6873    1.49    1   0   0   8.93
7041    1.43    1   0   0   8.94
6519    1.49    1   0   0   8.94
6028    1.49    1   0   0   8.93
6102    1.49    1   0   0   7.93
7249    1.49    1   0   0   7.93
6817    1.49    1   0   0   7.95
5621    1.49    1   0   0   6.94
5127    1.49    1   0   0   6.94
5183    1.44    1   0   0   6.94
4625    1.49    1   0   0   6.91
4915    1.50    1   0   0   6.9
4457    1.49    1   0   0   6.95
4324    1.49    1   0   0   6.95
3762    1.49    1   0   0   6.96
3477    1.48    0   0   0   7.74
3812    1.48    0   1   0   5.89
4719    1.46    0   1   0   6.68
5563    1.25    0   1   0   6.78
3828    1.47    0   1   0   7.55
3807    1.47    0   1   0   5.5
3465    1.46    0   1   0   7.68
3161    1.45    0   1   0   7.51
3107    1.48    0   1   0   5.73
2972    1.48    0   1   0   5.9
3445    1.49    0   1   0   5.89
3640    1.49    0   1   0   6.29
3398    1.49    0   0   1   6.29
3231    1.49    0   0   1   7.64
3556    1.49    0   0   1   7.71
4358    1.49    0   0   1   7.69
6020    1.50    0   0   1   7.67
5219    1.50    0   0   1   7.63
5419    1.49    0   0   1   5.46
5814    1.49    0   0   1   7.46
6061    1.49    0   0   1   7.42
6009    1.48    0   0   1   5.99
6842    1.49    0   0   1   7.53
5825    1.49    0   0   1   5.87
6311    1.49    0   0   0   5.86
7166    1.48    0   0   0   7.4
6308    1.49    0   0   0   7.44
6733    1.49    0   0   0   9.38
7387    1.49    0   0   0   7.95
10717   1.48    0   0   0   7.95
7712    1.49    0   0   0   8.61
5974    1.48    0   0   0   7.96
7788    1.24    0   0   0   7.96
8943    1.48    0   0   0   7.96
7455    1.49    0   0   0   7.98
```

I want to apply the power model which would require me to use `=LN(variable)` in Excel.

Do I omit my `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3` variables or transform them as well?

Comment: transforming a value of "1" LN(1) becomes "0" and then back transforming EXP(0) becomes "1" .. thus wouldn't it be okay to simply omit? This is why I am asking

Comment: I moved the tail of the discussion on "gender dummies" [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31123/discussion-on-question-by-johnson-jason-when-performing-a-linearizing-transforma).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about it this way. Consider any indicator variable with values $0$ and $1$. Call it $X$.

To preserve the distinction between those two values, you would have to map to two distinct values, say $a,b$. That transformation would be thus equivalent to $X' = a + (b - a)X$, so that $0$ goes to $a$ and $1$ goes to $a + (b - a) = b$. That is a linear transformation and indeed for simplicity you might as well choose $a = 0, b = 1$, and we have executed a perfect circle.

Another way to see that any one-to-one transformation of indicators is equivalent to a linear transformation is to see that geometrically it is defined by two points in the plane, differing on each coordinate, and those two points define a line uniquely.

If you changed to values other than $0, 1$ you lose the useful simplifications on plugging in $0$ and $1$ that make the indicator device so useful.

So no transformation could possibly be helpful and indeed no transformation is needed.

Furthermore, $\ln 0$ is undefined so logarithmic transformation is impossible any way. The reversibility of $\exp(\ln 1) \equiv 1$ is half a solution but fatally the other half of the problem is insoluble.

The question mentions only linearizing transformations but in other contexts there is often a false concern that predictors "should be" normally distributed. This is pure myth and indeed the use of indicators as predictors can serve as a counter-example. No indicator can be normally distributed as its frequency distribution is at most two spikes with fixed skewness and kurtosis and that distribution cannot be converted to any other shape. (A pedantic but unimportant exception is that the skewness might change sign if the spikes are flipped around.)

(Quite a different point, but I dislike the terminology **dummy variable**. One serious argument against it is that in some contexts it has been wildly misinterpreted as offensive. I have heard stories about angry confrontations in seminars to nontechnical audiences when researchers started talking about the "gender dummy". Or the term may unintentionally appear amusing to at least some of the audience, but crucially not all. See e.g. [the story here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2005-10/msg00594.html). The term is overloaded in mathematics any way and **indicator** conveys the meaning better. But tribal habits are strong and if your teachers or colleagues all say "dummy" it is simplest to follow along. Naturally yet other terms are available, including **binary** and **dichotomous**.)